# How to make ESP32 wake-up signal and standby signal using Android app via BLE

Tags: esp32, bluetooth-low-energy

I want to make an ESP32 device stand by and wake up using an Android app.

I know the ESP32 can be woken up using an external source but there is nothing much regarding using an app.

Answer (score 0):

It depends… If it’s in deepsleep, only a gpio (also ‘touch’) and timer can wake it up. (Also limited capabilities by the ultra lowpower processor ULP).

In lightsleep it could be possible, but it still uses a lot of power.

Comment: Can I get any code or way like blog etc?

Comment: Do you use Arduino or ESP-IDF? If the latter; if you start a new project and use a template you can choose a nice one. There is also a nice one with the ADC polled by the ULP-processor.  But those questions belong to stack overflow. :)

Comment: Okk got it thanks